# Error CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT when runs Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I use Android Studio on Windows 10, and it normally runs fine. But sometimes, you never know when it is going to happen, when the emulator is loading, it freezes and the Windows OS crashes, showing the blue screen (CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT).

I would like to know if exists any way to stop this strange behavior. I'm sure this is not related to the java code nor the functionality I am developing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

SS

Comment: Have this issue as well and it happens 100% of the times, the devices boots : Google screen, then freeze, then blue screen

Answer (score 1):

I had this for so long, reinstalling windows/updating drivers/updating bios, nothing worked.

It turned out it was a defect cpu. AMD replaced it and everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I never found the reason this behavior occurred.

My solution was to restaure Windows. After that, I reinstalled all my programs and softwares.
This way, the problem was solved.

Regards

SS

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck with this:

1. Windows search for "update settings"
2. in Update Settings window, click "View update history"
3. "Uninstall updates"
4. Under "Microsoft Windows", find the most recent "Security Update for Microsoft Windows".
5. Right click and uninstall

After uninstalling this update, I was able to use the Android emulator without any BSOD crashes. The security update will be replaced with an old security update (which will show in that list) and the one that is stable for me is KB4538461.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcXi4.png